# I try to count the same numbers of a column in a DF with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the occurrences of the same number in a column of a DF. These numbers represent the month of the year:

```
shoes_uk["Month"].head(10)

105    1
464    3
575    3
583    3
631    3
668    4
701    4
724    4
731    4
737    4
Name: Month, dtype: int64

month_14 = shoes_uk["Month"]

for m in month_14:
    for j in month_14:
        if m == j:
             su += 1
print (su)
```

The Idea is to have how many occurrences I got in Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. I'm not very good with loops, I've tried different combinations from the above code but I haven't get it yet

Comment: This is value counts with a month mapper if needed: `import calendar` , 
`shoes_uk['Month'].map(dict(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))).value_counts(sort=False)`

Comment: It worked just great 
df['Month'].map(dict(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))).value_counts(sort=False)
Out[12]:
Feb    228
Nov    205
Aug    302
Mar    210
Oct    265
May    246
Sep    242
Jan    186
Apr    291
Dec    247
Jul    254
Jun    276
Name: Month, dtype: int64  Thank you so much!